# PK e FK Conflito no Banco de Dados SQL Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc, entity-framework-6

Estou enfrentando um problema de conflito de Chave Primária e Chave Estrangeira no SQL Server 2017 Express. Estou usando ASP.NET com Entity Framework Code First (Migrations). O problema é que quando vou adicionar um novo Cliente que é uma Pessoa não adiciona. O Entity Framework até cria as tabelas com o relacionamento, coloca chave primária nas duas tabelas, coloca também o ClienteId como FK na tabela Cliente, porém não insere no banco.

**Erro ocorrido:**

SqlException: A instrução INSERT conflitou com a restrição do FOREIGN KEY "FK_Cliente_Pessoa". O conflito ocorreu no banco de dados "TesteTecnicoDB", tabela "dbo.Pessoa", column 'PessoaId'.
A instrução foi finalizada.

**Classe Cliente:**

```
public class Cliente
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Pessoa")]
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }

    public Cliente()
    {
        Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
        ClienteId = pessoa.PessoaId;
    }
}
```

**Classe Cliente Configuration**

```
public class ClienteConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cliente>
{
    public ClienteConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(c => c.ClienteId);
    }
}
```

**Classe Pessoa**

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public TipoPessoa TipoPessoa { get; set; }

    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public virtual PessoaFisica PessoaFisica { get; set; }
    public virtual PessoaJuridica PessoaJuridica { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Endereco> Enderecos { get; set; }
}
```

**Classe Pessoa Configuration**

```
public class PessoaConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Pessoa>
{
    public PessoaConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.PessoaId);
    }
}
```

**Tabelas no Banco:**

[image: Mapeamento no Banco de Dados]

Alguém sabe como pode ser resolvido este problema?

Comment: do jeito que ta ao que tudo indica você está tentando inserir em Pessoa um Id que ainda não existe em cliente

Comment: @Lucas Miranda

A idéia é inserir uma Pessoa e pegar o ID da pessoa e inserir na Tabela Cliente e na Tabela Pessoa Física se o cliente for uma pessoa física.

Consegui fazer Stored Procedures, porém não consigo mandar os dados das Views para o banco.